# Live database connection to ArcMap for Linear Referencing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

Is it possible to have a live ArcMap 10.4 connection to a database that will update database changes without the need to export the database table as a GDB?

Do I always have to do the export?

I mean this particularly in regards to linear referencing.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use Dynamic Segmentation so I think the answers are Yes and then No. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Well im not stuck anywhere but people I work around ask me often whether changes in the 11g database would quickly manifest themselves in the ArcMap map. I never quite know what to say.

Comment: But exporting the database table is the only way I know to bring in data to ArcMap. Aside from a spreasheet of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can [Connect to Oracle from ArcMap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/connect-oracle.htm#GUID-9D0EF07F-4E72-41EE-A4A0-CAF73BE2087A).

Once you can view an Oracle table you should be able to use it as an event table with [Dynamic Segmentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/dynamic-segmentation.htm):

> Geographic data is represented on a map as a layer. Route events are
>   no different. To display route events on a map, however, you must
>   first define the parameters of the relationship between the table
>   storing the events and the routes that the events reference.

The technology used to do this has a long history that dates from 1989 and Esri UK's Chainage Module and Highway Information System (ArcHIS) which became the Dynamic Segmentation capability of ARC/INFO a year or two later.  It was using Oracle to store event tables then so I would not expect that functionality to have been lost in the intervening years.

Comment: OK that sounds good. How do I go about doing that? Is there a function for it in the toolbox? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: @hollow_Victory Have you been able to connect to and view Oracle tables in ArcMap yet?  If that is where you are stuck try using the first documentation link that I provided.  If you are still stuck then research/ask how to connect to and view Oracle tables in ArcMap as a separate question.

Comment: I am connected to an Oracle database right now and I can access the tables. As far as viewing them, do you mean exporting the table as a single geodatabase?